# Mentions in Framework and Emulator always empty

Tags: c#, botframework

I remember, that I was able to mention the bot with @foobot when I was working with the older Emulator and Botframework V3.

Now I decided to give V4 a try - but I can't get any mentions with the emulator.

The `context.Activity.GetMentions()` always returns an empty array of mentions. I tried a lot of different names (Bot, the bot-guid, foobot, emulator etc.).

Was this somehow changed? I have no idea how I could try to react to any mention without setting up remote debugging and deploying to Azure - which is way to much work for development in my opinion.

Further - is it possible to get a UserState to a mentioned person?

Thanks in advance,
Fabian

Comment: What is the `context` you are referring to? In v-4 we now have `TurnContext` which pretty much holds most of the information. Refer this- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.mention?view=botbuilder-dotnet-preview

Comment: The V4 docs has [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-activities-entities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#mention-entities) on mentions, so they are still supported.

Comment: Yes I’m referring to the TurnContext. And indeed I use the GetMentions method. But my problem is about mentions in combination with the Bot Emulator - I didn’t find a way to fill the mentions object when addressing the bot in any way.